# Sum of elements in a nested weighted by their depth

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a nested list of integers, returns the sum of all integers in the list weighted by their depth

For example, given the list {{1,1},2,{1,1}} the function should return 10 (four 1's at depth 2, one *2 at depth 1)

Given the list {1,{4,{6}}} the function should return 27 (one 1 at depth 1, one 4 at depth 2, and *one 6 at depth 3)

```
public int depthSum (List<NestedInteger> input)
{
     //Implement this function
}

/**
 * This is the interface that allows for creating nested lists. You should not implement it, or speculate about its implementation
 */
public interface NestedInteger 
{
    // Returns true if this NestedInteger holds a single integer, rather than a nested list
    public boolean isInteger();

    // Returns the single integer that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a single integer
    // Returns null if this NestedInteger holds a nested list
    public Integer getInteger();

    // Returns the nested list that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a nested list
    // Returns null if this NestedInteger holds a single integer
    public List<NestedInteger> getList();
}
```

Comment: what you have tried? show us the code.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I tried with below code.. but not able to track depth properly

 private static int getSum(Object list, int depth, int curSum) {
  if (list == null)
   return 0;

  if (list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
   for (Object nestedList : (ArrayList<Object>) list) {
    curSum += getSum(nestedList, depth + 1, curSum);
   }
  } else {
   curSum += (Integer) list * depth;
   System.out.println("CurrentSum => "+curSum + " integer => "+ list+ " Depth => "+depth);
  }
  return curSum;
 }

Comment: @ Debobroto Das, I belive he nothing triing as "Can anyone provide java code for this?"

Comment: @ Толя, Sorry.. i tried.. But couldn't exactly carry over depth during recursion.... just looking where exactly i did wrong

Comment: Finally able to solve myself.  Found issue with my code and fixed

Comment: Finally this is not for knowing code.. It is for knowing algorithm.
Finally i tried and got solution on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NestedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // {{1,1},2,{1,1}}
        List<Object> parent1 = new ArrayList<Object>();

        List<Object> child1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        child1.add(1);
        child1.add(1);
        parent1.add(child1);

        parent1.add(2);

        List<Object> child3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        child3.add(1);
        child3.add(1);
        parent1.add(child3);

        System.out.println(getSum(parent1, 1));

        // {1,{4,{6}}}
        List<Object> parent2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        parent2.add(1);

        List<Object> child11 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        child11.add(4);

        List<Object> child111 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        child111.add(6);

        child11.add(child111);
        parent2.add(child11);
        System.out.println(getSum(parent2, 1));
    }

    private static int getSum(Object list, int depth) {
        if (list == null)
            return 0;

        int sum = 0;
        if (list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
            for (Object nestedList : (ArrayList<Object>) list) {
                if (nestedList.getClass() == ArrayList.class)
                    sum += getSum(nestedList, depth + 1);
                else
                    sum += getSum(nestedList, depth);
            }
        } else {
            sum += (Integer) list * depth;
            System.out.println("CurrentSum => " + sum + " integer => " + list
                    + " Depth => " + depth);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've corrected your code. You don't need to take the if statement in the loop there. Because if the object is a list, then you should have already added the depth by one.

Comment: @ justhalf, edit you made was incorrect. Please test the code after making changes

Comment: Oops, I thought this was your incorrect attempt. So this is correct, right?

Comment: I give another shorter and more intuitive alternative as `getSumFromList`

Comment: Yes. this is the correct and tested solution.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is very simple.

Given that you have the string of nested array like {{1,1},2,{1,1}},
Just iterate through the string and keep track of the number of braces that have not been closed. The depth of the current element shall be equal to the number of open brackets till that point.

For example for {{1,1},2,{1,1}}

```
1. Read 1st two characters. The counter for number of open braces is 2.
2. Hence the depth of both the 1s read = 2.
3. Then a closing brace appears, so decrement the counter.
4. The depth of 2 shall be 1.
5. Likewise for the remaining elements.
```

EDIT: for a NestedInteger Interface, you can modify the above algorithm and implement it using recursion. Following is a plausible pseudocode.

```
public int getSum( List<NestedInteger> input, int currDepth ) {

  int sum = 0;
//  iterate through the list.
  if ith element is an Integer, then sum += currDepth*element; // simply add the element to sum
  else  sum += getSum( element, currDepth + 1 ); // get sum for that particular nested list.
  return sum;

}


public int depthSum (List<NestedInteger> input)
{
     return getSum( input, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't give much context. Input is not a string. I have to use the interface provided in input and solve the problem

Comment: Edited my answer to provide the pseudocode for the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a stack for this.

Suppose the string is `{{1,1},2,{1,1}}`.

```
Step 1: Go through the string to determine its depth.
```

You can do this by initializing variables `depth =0` and `maxdepth=depth`;
Everytime you encounter a '{' increment `depth` and if `depth>maxdepth`, `maxdepth=depth`.
If you encounter a '}', decrement `depth`.

The final value of `maxdepth` will be the depth of the string. In this case `maxdepth=2`;

```
Step 2: Declare an array items_depth to the depth given by maxdepth.
Integer[] items_depth = new Integer[maxdepth+1];
```

`items_depth` gives the number of items at any depth. Initialize all the elements in `items_depth` to 0. (Initially there are zero items at any depth). I assume 0 depth as well. So, for depth 2 there will be items at three depths 0,1,2.

```
Step 3: Go through the string again from left to right
int depth =0;
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
while(there are characters in the string)
{    char i = current character;
     if(i=='{')
     {
         depth++;
     }
     if(i is an integer)
     {
         items_depth[depth]++;
         stack.push(Integer.parseInt(i));
     }
     if(i==',')
     {
         continue;

     }
     if(i=='}')
     {
         int temp= items_depth[depth];
         int temp_depth = depth;
         depth--;
         int temp_sum=0;


         for(int i=1;i<=items_depth[temp_depth] && items_depth[temp_depth]>0;i++)
         {
          temp_sum+=stack.pop();   
         }
         items_depth[temp_depth]=0;
         stack.push(temp_sum);
         item_depth[depth]++; 
     }

}
return stack.pop();
```

The last item popped from the stack will be the sum of the term with the depths as weight. I assumed a single character int. You have to modify the code to accomodate other ints

Comment: give solution for given input which nested list structure. don't assume input as string